# Dynamically generating mappings between POJOs and REST API

Tags: java, json, rest, pojo

I have a POJO class and I need to call a RESTful web  service using some properties from the POJO as parameters to the service. The caveat is that I won't know the endpoint and its parameters 'till runtime. Basically, the user will configure at runtime the endpoint, input/output schemas and mappings from/to those schemas to the POJO class. Then I have to call the API with the appropriate values.

Comment: This question is likely too broad, even though it's a good question there are too many different ways to answer it. I'd recommend trying something, or asking something a little more specific, or trying an alternate Stack Exchange site.

That said, If you can limit the scope to say, a JSON web service, or an XML web service, with some specific example schema's, someone will likely be able to give you a hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a really broad answer.

It sounds like a question that would benefit as 'code as data'.

What I mean by this, is that the amount of possibilities that you have to be able to deal with at runtime, is close to the complexities of using a programming language itself.

When this happens, there's generally a few choices that people either choose by accident, or consciously choose depending on who the user is.

1. Limit the scope of the problem, and make your configuration that complex it may as well be a programming language itself.
2. Embed a scripting language, or create some runtime loading of plugins in the native language.
3. Use an off the shelf library / solution.

I'd recommend 2 or 3 over 1 if your user is yourself or the configuration can be provided by another programmer.